# What is meant by OpenERP fields.reference?

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I saw this code segment in **subscription.py** class. It gives selection and many2one fields together for users. I found in openerp documentation and another modules also but i never found any details or other samples for this

here is the its view

[image: fields.reference]

here is the code related to that field

```
'doc_source': fields.reference('Source Document', required=True, selection=_get_document_types, size=128),
```

here is the selection part function code

```
def _get_document_types(self, cr, uid, context=None):
    cr.execute('select m.model, s.name from subscription_document s, ir_model m WHERE s.model = m.id order by s.name')
    return cr.fetchall()
```

I Need to know that; can we make our own fields.reference type fields.?

another combination instead of MODEL,NAME..?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the OpenERP framework a `fields.reference` field is a pseudo-`many2one` relationship that can target multiple models. That is, it contains the name of the target model in addition to the foreign key, so that each value can belong to a different table. The user interface first presents a drop-down where the user selects the target document model, and then a `many2one` widget in which they can pick the specific document from that model.
You can of course use it in your own modules, but it will always behave in this manner.

This is typically used for attaching various documents (similarly to attachments except the target is another record rather than a file). It's also used in some internal OpenERP models that need to be attached to different types of record, such as properties (`fields.property` values) that may belong to any record.

The `fields.reference` [constructor](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp/openobject-server/7.0/view/5044/openerp/osv/fields.py#L182) takes 3 main parameters:

```
'doc': fields.reference('Field Label', selection, size)
```

where `selection` contains the list of document models from which values can be selected (e.g Partners, Products, etc.), in the same form as in a [`fields.selection`](https://doc.openerp.com/trunk/server/03_module_dev_02/#basic-types) declaration. The key of the selection values must be the model names (e.g. `'res.partner'`).

As of OpenERP 7.0 the `size` parameter should be `None`, unless you want to specifically restrict the size of the database field where the values will be stored, which is probably a bad idea. Technically, `fields.reference` values are stored as text in the form `model.name,id`. You won't be able to use these fields in a regular SQL JOIN, so they won't behave like `many2one` fields in many cases.

**Main API calls**

- When you programmatically `read()` a non-null reference value you have to split it on `','` to identify the target model and target ID
- When you programmatically `write()` a non-null reference value you need to pass the `'model.name,id'` string.
- When you `search()` for a non-null reference value you need to search for the `'model.name,id'` string (e.g. in a search domain)
- Finally, when you `browse()` through a reference value programmatically the framework will automatically dereference it and follow the relationship as with a regular `many2one` field - this is the main exception to the rule ;-)

Comment: Is it possible to add a tree view (& form view) for the chosen model?